# Как разместить картинки в один ряд, с текстом под ними

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Добрый день у меня вопрос как разместить картинки как на скриншоте.

Код моей попытки смотрите ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
    background: url(../img/bg1.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
    height: 900px
}
.container{
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    float: left;
}
nav{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
.menu{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact{
    padding: 0;
    margin:-50px;
    display: block;
}
.contact li1{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right:-130px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.contact li1 a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.facebook{
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.twitter{
    float:right;
    margin-right:-10px;     
}
.email{
    float:right;
    margin-right:-50px; 
}
.titles_first{
    font-size:60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
h1{
    font-size:;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;

}
.title{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.title h2{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #000000;
}
.title p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}
#welcome{
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#whatwedo{
    background: #D3D3D3;
}
.works{
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.services{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.services h3{
    color: #4169E1;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.services p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.55em;
}
.services:last-child{
    float: right;
}
.services:nth-child(1){
    margin-left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>www</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="conteiner">
            <div class="heading clearfix">
            <img src="img/EVENT TECH SERVICES.png" alt="SERVICES" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                   <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Kit</a>
                    <a href="#">Custom</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>

                   </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                   <nav>
                    <ul class="contact">
                        <li1>
                            <a href="Tel">T:01443229766 |</a>
                            <a href="Email">E:info@eventteck.com</a>
                                <img src="img/email.png" alt="ema" class="email">   
                                <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitt" class="twitter">
                                <img src="img/f.png" alt="facc" class="facebook">

                        </li1>
                    </ul>                   
                   </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="titles">
            <div class="titles_first">End To End Technical Solutions</div>
                <h1>For The Audio And Video Industry</h1>
             </div>

    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="conteiner">
           <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Welcome to event tech services
            </h2>
            <p>
                Event tech services is an innovative solution to live events, offering first class, tailored services to public and private busiesses.
            </p>
            <p>
                You can find more information about the services we offer on this website if you would like to your vespokie recommended please contact us.
            </p>
           </div>           
        </div>

    </section>
    <section id="whatwedo">
        <div class="conteiner">
            <div class='title'>
                <h2>What we do</h2>
                <p>We offer dry hier rhrough to bespoke, fully managed solutions using our own equlpment. We have a wide expreilance in range of production envioments incloud live event production and so we understad that showtime is go time. </p>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="works clearfix">
                <div class="services">
                    <img src="img/audio.png">
                    <h3>Audio</h3>
                    <p>Solutions for all need PA for comfortable sound.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="services">
                    <img src="img/stage.png">
                    <h3>Stage</h3>
                    <p>We can provide podiums and sages of any sure and design.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="services">
                    <img src="img/light.png">
                    <h3>Light</h3>
                    <p>We can supply a wilde range of ligh for decoration stage.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="services">
                    <img src="img/commubications.png">
                    <h3>Communications</h3>
                    <p>HandSheld radio packs for sure of stage voice and werless.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="conteiner">

        </div>

    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="conteiner">

        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свой код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так - если что то не то - скажите я подправлю

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%
}

.item h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b9f2ff;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

.item p {
  margin: 6px 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x100" alt="">
    <h3>Какое то название</h3>
    <p>Описание этого блока, очевидно полезное но точно отображаюшее суть этого блока</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x100" alt="">
    <h3>Какое то название</h3>
    <p>Описание этого блока, очевидно полезное но точно отображаюшее суть этого блока</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x100" alt="">
    <h3>Какое то название</h3>
    <p>Описание этого блока, очевидно полезное но точно отображаюшее суть этого блока</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x100" alt="">
    <h3>Какое то название</h3>
    <p>Описание этого блока, очевидно полезное но точно отображаюшее суть этого блока</p>
  </div>

</div>
```